# Как извлечь integer из сообщения?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Например, при отправке !clear очищались бы все сообщения в канале, но при отправке !clear `число` очищалось бы некоторое количество сообщений, указанных числом. Нужно как то получить это число из всего текста сообщения.

Пример кода, в котором нужно это сделать:

```
async def on_message(message):
if message.guild.id == 624170997284732928:
    if message.content == "!clear":
        deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit=число сообщений)
        message = await message.channel.send(":wastebusket: Deleted `{0}` message(s).".format(len(deleted)))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел как решить проблему:

```
    if re.search(r"\d+$", message.content) is not None:
        count = int(message.content[len('!clear'):].strip())
    else:
        count = math.inf
    deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit=count)
```

Так, при вводе !clear будут удаляться все сообщения, а при вводе !clear `число` будет удаляться то количество, которое указано в команде.

При этом нужно сделать `import re` и `import math` в код.
(Либо, чтобы не импортить math - заменить `math.inf` в коде на какое нибудь большое число, например, 9999)

Answer (score 0):

Если команда начинается с "`!clear`”, то разделяем команду по пробелам берем элемент после первого пробела в качестве лимита:

```
if message.content.startswith("!clear"):
    limit = message.content.split()[1]
    deleted = await message.channel.purge(limit)
    и т д
```

Команда должна иметь формат `!clear число`. Если нет, то будет ошибка.